# UILabel as tableViewCell's accessoryView is shifted up

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilabel, vertical-alignment

I am creating a normal UILabel and setting it as tableViewCell's accessoryView. My understanding is, accessoryView stays vertically centre aligned inside cell. But that is not happening. As I decrease the label text's font, the accessory view moves more upwards. Button works just fine. Problem with UILabel.

[image]

Here is my code :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Hello"

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 42, height: 21))
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 12)
    label.highlightedTextColor = UIColor.white
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.textColor = UIColor.green
    label.textAlignment = .right;
    label.clipsToBounds = true
    label.autoresizesSubviews = true
    label.contentMode = .left
    label.text = "123";

    cell.accessoryView = label
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution. The frame that I was giving to UILabel was CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 42, height: 21). If I give the height same as the text size i.e. 12.0, The label becomes centre aligned :). 
This seems like an iOS 13 issue. Not seen in iOS 12 devices.

`let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 42, height: 12))`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that there is an iOS 13 issue. However, your solution doesn't work on iOS 14.4, which also has the problem of vertically aligning the `UILabel` in the cell. The solution with the container `UIView` from @Raimundas Sakalauskas does work.

Answer (score 4):

As @Faizyy has noticed, there's an issue with iOS 13, however providing small height is not always an option. My approach was to put UILabel into UIView of the same size as UILabel and use that container view as accessory view. This has solved alignment issues for me. Here's an example:

```
cell.accessoryView = [self getBadge:unread];

-(UIView *)getBadge:(int)count {
    CGFloat size = 28;
    CGFloat digits = [[@(count) stringValue] length];
    CGFloat width = MAX(size, 0.7 * size * digits);

    UILabel *badge = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, size)];
    badge.text = [@(count) stringValue];
    badge.layer.cornerRadius = size / 2;
    badge.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    badge.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    badge.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Medium" size:16];
    badge.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor;
    badge.backgroundColor = VSColor.blue;

    UIView *badgeHolder = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, size)];
    badgeHolder.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
    [badgeHolder addSubview:badge];

    return badgeHolder;
}
```

Comment: This is a working solution, thanks for this idea. The container is even required on iOS 14.4, so it's not only related to iOS 13. One small suggestion for improvement is to use the badge frame size when declaring the container: `UIView *badgeHolder = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:badge.frame];`

Answer (score 0):

If you are working pre SwiftUI, you should consider using auto layout to center the UILabel to the cell to prevent it from moving up. If you're using SwiftUI, you have to use SwiftUI Layout System. Hope that helps.